Integrating GTM with Pardot Iframe and make tag dependent on parent cookie banner choice
I have multiple forms created in Pardot and I'm trying to figure out how to track the form submissions in GA and GTM while being GDPR compliant. I control both the parent, iframe nad GTM container. The parent domain is example.com and the iframe is created by Pardot (Salesforce) @ go.example.com.
My cookie Banner is Complianz and this creates a cmplz_marketing cookie that i'm using as an exception on my trigger. If they accept the cookies it's set to allow and if they reject it's set to deny. This works fine on all the tags that are on example.com, but on my iframe in my GTM container this cookie is set to undefined.
I have the GTM script pasted in the head/body of my main site and the head/body of the iframe and upon form submission, the iframe sends a pardot_form_submit data layer event.
